# Error in generating Android incremental OTA package

Tags: android, linux, android-source, ota

I was able to build Android image for my Development Board by applying my custom patch to AOSP code. The generated binaries(Say Version 1) was working fine. I have made few changes to my patch, built the latest image(Say Version 2). This also working good.

I have respective target_files for these versions by running dist command

```
make dist
```

**What worked:**

When i try to generate incremental ota package on my Linux machine(say PC-1), the ota.zip file was generated and working fine.

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i ./version1_target_file.zip ./version2_target_file.zip oat_file_version_1_to_2.zip 
unzipping target target-files...
unzipping source target-files...
unable to load device-specific module; assuming none
Loading target...
Loading source...
2 diffs to compute
    0.41 sec      316 /   307886 bytes (  0.10%) system/etc/recovery-resource.dat
    1.43 sec     1799 /  2521277 bytes (  0.07%) system/priv-app/Calander.apk
building image from target_files BOOT...
building image from target_files BOOT...
building image from target_files RECOVERY...
building image from target_files RECOVERY...
boot      target: 5414912  source: 5414912  diff: 1086759
boot image changed; including.
recovery image changed; including as patch from boot.
done.
```

**What not worked:**

The same when tried in another Linux PC(other than PC-1), there are dependency error making my script to fail.

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i ./version1_target_file.zip ./version2_target_file.zip oat_file_version_1_to_2.zip 
unzipping target target-files...
unzipping source target-files...
unable to load device-specific module; assuming none
Loading target...
Loading source...
2 diffs to compute
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 919, in worker
    d.ComputePatch()
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 879, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 68, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 919, in worker
    d.ComputePatch()
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 879, in ComputePatch
    p = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 68, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory


building image from target_files BOOT...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 914, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 899, in main
    WriteIncrementalOTAPackage(input_zip, source_zip, output_zip)
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 605, in WriteIncrementalOTAPackage
    OPTIONS.source_info_dict)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 344, in GetBootableImage
    info_dict))
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 281, in BuildBootableImage
    p1 = Run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/ubuntu/otaPackageBuildTest/test/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 68, in Run
    return subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Question:**
What are the minimal packages required to generate incremental ota file on  a fresh Linux PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install all necessary AOSP libs as stated from: https://source.android.com/source/initializing

For Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04:

> sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential
>   zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386
>   lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache
>   libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip

Also, sometimes its helps to pass in the host arch (-p arg) and verbose option (-v) to get more debugging information from the command itself:

I.E.

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -v --block -p out/host/linux-x86 -k build/target/product/security/releasekey -i previous_signed_target_files.zip signed_target_files.zip incremental.zip
```